# Obscured object segmentation in binary segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I am using deep learning for building outline segmentation. I have used binary segmentation method using **UNet** model which runs on **Tensorflow 2.0**. The output is fine when there are no other object (Ex. Trees) obscures the building. But when building is under the tree, it produces incorrect segmentation results. *Please refer screenshots below*

**Raw image:**

[image: Raw_image]

**Segmentation result overlaid:**
[image: Segmentation result]

**What I want!**

[image]

**Details of output:**
Input for the segmentation is raw image and output is a raster containing building segmentation where building pixels are classified as 1 and non building pixels are classified as 0 using UNet deep learning trained model

**My requirement:**
I want the output prediction for the obscured areas (marked as green boundary in the above screenshot). Current segmentation method fails to predict that as building as it is barely visible in the input image.

**My attempt:**
So far I have not attempted to fix this problem, any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What does your ground truth segmentation look like in this case? As far as I can see there is not direct visual information that actually shows the building, and it is therefore difficult for the model to know (probably for humans as well) that the house continues below the tree. If your dataset has the extra pixels annotated as a building the model might learn that buildings generally have straight edges.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I didn't annotate where the building cannot be seen visually in the ground truth. Even if I annotate these areas as building, I am not getting the expected output. It actually worsened the result badly

Comment: If you didn't annotate those extra areas than the model will not learn that those areas are buildings since it would increase the loss. The only to improve the result in these cases would be to add an extra (handcrafted) layer on top of the model's prediction using computer vision techniques, but that might cause issues for cases where the model is currently giving correct predictions.

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean by extra layer? Could you please explain in detail

Comment: You could add an extra postprocessing step to the output of the model (e.g. make sure the region selected is square) but as mentioned that will likely impact the performance for the cases where the result of the model is correct.

Comment: Are you saying to use GAN as a postprocessing step? or do you have any specific suggestion for this case?